# Are hentai related questions allowed on this stack?

Tags: discussion

I have this manga identification question to ask. I think its more hentai than manga. I just wanted to make sure if it is safe to ask a hentai related question so that I don't get into trouble.

Comment: I migrated this question again. Please do not delete it.

Comment: the question has been already asked [before](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21/is-discussing-hentai-allowed?rq=1) . So I thought there was no need to repeat it again

Comment: That's what marking as duplicate is for ;)

Comment: Lol that's why I tried to delete it , before you could mark it ;)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha why is marking a Q as duplicate more satisfying than letting me delete the Q ? jk :D